# How can I delete a SharePoint sub site using SharePoint web services?

Tags: sharepoint

I am forced to use SharePoint web services. I need a web service which will let me delete the SharePoint sub site. I have tried to use DeleteWorkspace method (Meetings.asmx web service), but it is capable of only deleting the sub sites that are meeting workspaces (mine uses a custom template derived from team site). Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazingly! No you can't do it.... I know! weird that it would left out.  I'm sure there was a decision made somehwere about but beats me if I know why.

The only option is to deploy custom code - either an event receiver or a web service.

Comment: @DJ: It's not that weird. There's huge amounts of functionality missing in those web services. Anticipating this will be resolved for SharePoint 2010!

Comment: Come on Alex, DeleteSite is there DeleteList etc but the web object is missed?  Thats weird in my book.

Comment: @DJ: I think we agree here. Your point is that the web services provide inconsistent functionality. My point is that they miss functionality altogether. End result: they suck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. SharePoint web services suck big time so far.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't possible with the out-of-the-box web services. (They only have functionality for deletion at the site collection level.)

You would need to develop a [custom web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx) and deploy that to your SharePoint farm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. SharePoint web services suck big time so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to SharePoint 2013, there is a new method in the [`Sites`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsites.sites.aspx) web service: [`DeleteWeb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsites.sites.deleteweb.aspx). It expects URL of the subsite to delete, relative to the site that you connected the web service to.

---   Ferda

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a site try using the dws webservice.

I used `DWS.DeleteDWS()` where the functoins `get_constant` etc. simple get back constants for login and webservices like `_vti_bin/dws.asmx`

```
Public Function RemoveWSSSite(ByVal sPath As String, ByVal sSubSiteName As String) As Boolean
        Dim DTConstant As New DTFrameWork.DTConstant
        Dim SPDWS1 As New SPDws.Dws
        Dim sSubsiteURL As String = ""

        If (sSubSiteName = "") Then
            sSubsiteURL = ""
        Else
            sSubsiteURL = sSubSiteName & "/"
        End If
        SPDWS1.PreAuthenticate = True
        SPDWS1.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(DTconst.Get_Constant_String_Value("SP_m_AdminUser"), DTconst.Get_Constant_String_Value("SP_m_AdminPassword"), DTconst.Get_Constant_String_Value("SP_m_SiteDomain"))
        SPDWS1.Url = DTconst.Get_Constant_String_Value("SP_m_SiteServerName") & IIf(sPath.StartsWith("/"), "", "/") & sPath & IIf(sPath.EndsWith("/"), "", "/") & sSubsiteURL & DTconst.Get_Constant_String_Value("SP_m_dws_asmx")
        Try

            SPDWS1.DeleteDws()

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

like Ben Says, using **/_vti_bin/Dws.asmx** should be works. Here's another example

```
public bool  DeleteSubSite(string urlSubSite, string user, string passw, string domain)
    {
        bool retValue = true;
        Dws docWS = new Dws();
        docWS.Url = urlSubSite + "/_vti_bin/Dws.asmx"; ;
        docWS.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, passw, domain);

        try
        {
            docWS.DeleteDws();
        }
        catch (SoapException soex)
        {
            retValue = false;
        }
        return retValue;
    }
```